# Как создать массив по последнему символу и сделать сортировку в порядке убывания на С++?

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Мне надо прочитать в программе текстовый файл и занести 10 строк в массив, но при этом надо ещё сделать сортировку по последнему символу в порядке убывания(Между числами/словами использовал Tab, не пробел)

В данный момент я могу только сами строки занести в массив, но не последний символ + программа для сортировки уже готова (Метод пузырька)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверное  не по последнему символу, а по последнему выражению

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы храните строками и строки нужно сортировать - то при сравнении вам нужно сравнивать именно последние... гм, символы.

Т.е. там где в сортировке *обычно* стоит что-то типа `a[i] < a[j]`, у вас должно быть `lastsym(a[i]) < lastsym(a[j])`.

Сама эта `char lastsym(const char*s)` - если вам нужен именно **символ** - реализуется просто: `return s[strlen(s)-1];`. Но если нужно последнее поле - то я бы шел с конца до первого табулятора, потом - на символ вперед и преобразование строки в значение типа `double`, да хоть простейшей `atof`, хотя, конечно, есть и более правильные и надежные варианты. Но для учебного задания - вполне сойдет.